# Is it possible to move the "Primary Hierarchy" Public Folder mailbox in Exchange 2013?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2013, public-folders

We want to delete one of our mailbox databases but before doing that, all mailboxes need to be moved/migrated to a different database. One of these mailboxes is a Public Folder mailbox and it also happens to be the Primary Hierarchy.

I read somewhere that without the Primary Hierarchy, all secondary PF mailboxes will not be accessible and something happening to the primary could be disastrous.

Since the primary hierarchy is unique is it still okay to migrate it to a different database and will the migration cause any downtime for other PF mailboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the migration will cause downtime which depends on the size of the public folder mailbox, the move may take several hours to complete. During that time, users won’t be able to access the public folders. Users also won’t have access to public folders for a brief period while the folder is in the “Completion in Progress” state. Details see: `[Move a public folder mailbox to a different mailbox database][1]`

Comment: Thanks for the response! Downtime is fine but moving the primary hierarchy can cause no other issues such as access corruption of the other public folders or something?

Comment: In theory, this will not cause any issue.